# VS2015 - Apache Cordova - Ionic Debugging on remote iOs simulator - Fails

Tags: ios, visual-studio, ionic-framework, remote-debugging, visual-studio-cordova

I am reaching out to anyone with experiance developing cross platform Ionic Apps in Visual Studio 2015, specifically debugging using the iOs Simulator on a remote Mac using remotebuild.

I am using Windows 10 64x, and have all the latest updates for Visual Studio 2015 and tools, likewise I have the latest iOs (Sierra 10.12.1) and XCode (8.0). NPM 3.10.8 (Mac & Win) and Node.js v6.9.1 (Mac & Win).

I can debug perfectly fine using an Android or Windows device Virtualisation on Windows.

Likewise I can issue a build via remotebuild just fine on the Mac from Visual Studio, it even runs the simulator and starts the app, however the debug process never attaches and I am left with VS in the ready to code state (not debugging) and an app running in iOs simulator.

I am no getting any meaningful error messages, below is an excerpt from the remotebuild component on the MAC, we see that the build goes through and succeeds, it then starts up the emulator :

```
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.2.0&cfg=debug&buildNumber=12887&loglevel=silly
{"accept-language":"en-US","host":"192.168.2.186:3000","connection":"close","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}

Downloading: taco-remote-multiplexer
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/wipserve/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/package.json'
npm WARN latest No description
npm WARN latest No repository field.
npm WARN latest No README data
npm WARN latest No license field.

taco-remote-multiplexer downloaded and installed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/wipserve/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/tacoRemoteMultiplexer.js'
Build will be executed under: /Users/wipserve/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/12887
Saving build request payload to : /Users/wipserve/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/12887
Saved uploaded build to /Users/wipserve/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/12887/upload_12887.tgz
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.2.0&cfg=debug&buildNumber=12887&loglevel=silly 202 5397.960 ms - 710
GET /cordova/build/tasks/12887 200 1.449 ms - 710
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/wipserve/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/12887/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 12887 as current build
Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /cordova/build/tasks/12887 200 1.343 ms - 753
GET /cordova/build/tasks/12887/log 200 1.893 ms - -
GET /cordova/build/12887/emulate?target=iPhone%205 - - ms - -
```

At the same as it calls /emulate VS stops 'waiting' so to speak and reports `Timed out launching the app. Check your network connection to the mac and try again` message, interestingly, this comes from the intellisense output(???). It seems not to wait at all but instead gets a bad response and aborts. I say this as I have modified my RemoteBuild.config to wait a massive amount of time :

```
{
  "serverDir": "/Users/wipserve/.taco_home/remote-builds",
  "port": 3000,
  "secure": true,
  "pinTimeout": 1000,
  "hostname": "XXXXXXXXX.local",
  "writePidToFile": false,
  "lang": "en-GB",
  "suppressSetupMessage": false,
  "type": "literal",
  "modules": {
    "taco-remote": {
      "mountPath": "cordova",
      "maxBuildsInQueue": 10,
      "maxBuildsToKeep": 20,
      "deleteBuildsOnShutdown": false,
      "allowsEmulate": true,
      "appLaunchStepTimeout": 6000000,
      "emulatorLaunchTimeout": 6000000,
      "nativeDebugProxyPort": 3001,
      "webDebugProxyDevicePort": 9221,
      "webDebugProxyRangeMin": 9222,
      "webDebugProxyRangeMax": 9322
    }
  }
}
```

In the interest of full disclosure, there is one more warning, tho old `Could not find development team. Starting with XCode 8, you must provide a build.json with a development team. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833112 for more details.` one, I am awaiting apple to accept my companies Development team application to sort this, for mow I have created a build.json and put a dud ID in there. This wouldn't stop the debugger from attaching would it?

I have been through miriad help topics on this and none of the "goto" solutions seem to be working (Setting larger timeouts, removing files, ect).

Happy to supply whatever files needed (FYI, I am using a blank Ionic Template for this test!), also attached is the build log from the mac, and the build output from VS.

All help greatly appriciated, please don't just mark this as a duplicate of an unanswered question or a question I've covered already, but please do post a link and if it turns out to be a dupe I will gladly commit hari kari and fall on my sword!

[Mac Build Log](http://autoglympro.cygstage.co.uk/files/build.log)

[VS Build Log](http://autoglympro.cygstage.co.uk/files/VS-Build-Log.txt)

Happy to confirm particular file contents, configs and/or anything else, just add a comment! I'll be monitoring this question 9 to 6 GMT as this is fast becoming an impasse for me. I am also happy to enter discussion between these times, feel fre to catch me in a SE Chat or my skype ID is blatant_uk (please add "Discussion RE StackOverflow Ionic Question" in your request so I know its not a spam!)

Here's hoping there's some guru's out there (I know that the VS taco team do hang around on here too!) that knocks out Ionic apps on Windows all the live long day that can help me get my baseline project up and running!

A massive thanks in advance for reading and any help offered!!

Comment: in order to reach the taco team correct tag is `visual-studio-cordova` , for future question use that tag.. , coming to your question even i'm  facing the same problem , you can raise an issue in the github under their repository , here is the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues)

Comment: Hi Webruster, thanks for adding that tag. It is sadly a stale issue now though, I have since moved on to other projects also so have not had cause to revisit this yet (who knows what the next few months will bring though?!). I do wonder whats happened especially since we're into VS 2017 territory now prhaps theres been improvement all around,, 
I will come back with answer if I do get a chance to revist (assuming any success these days!)

Comment: Even this issue persist in the VS2017 also as i raised issue in Github ..